# Not able to load an image in Angular 6 using cornerstonejs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm relatively new to Angular 6.
I am trying to include [cornerstonejs](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone) in my Angular 6 application. But I am encountering this error:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'cornerstone-core/dist/cornerstone.js'

I have installed cornerstone-core using `npm install cornerstone-core`.

Can someone point out, why this code is not working?

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as cornerstone from 'cornerstone-core/dist/cornerstone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'image-stack-viewer',
  templateUrl: './image-stack-viewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-stack-viewer.component.css']
})
export class ImageStackViewerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('testpod') canvasDiv: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const imageId = ''//my-mage-url;

    var element = this.canvasDiv;
    cornerstone.enable(this.canvasDiv);
    cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function (image:any) {
      cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);  
    });
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div #testpod width="500" height="400"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare cornerstone like that:

```
declare const cornerstone;
```

Take a look at this repository to find examples: https://github.com/avatsaev/angular-cornerstone-example